# Unable to send data to response after pipeline failed

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to query some data from mysql, transform it to csv and then finally download it as csv. Goal is to achieve this using streams.

```js
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
    res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${req.query?.filename || 'export'}.csv"`)
    const sqlStream = connection.query('SELECT * FROM whatever_table').stream({highWaterMark: 5}) // --> using mysql2 adapter
    const formatCsvStream = formatCsv({delimiter: ';'}) // --> using @fast-csv/format
    try {
        // using {pipeline} from require('stream/promises')
        await pipeline(
            sqlStream,
            formatCsvStream,
            res // --> express response
        )
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'Please check the application logs for more details.'}).end()
    }
```

Everything is working as expected if there are no errors before it pipes to response. But if errors do happen (for example we select data from table that is not existing in db) browser will respond with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE instead of sending json error message defined in catch block.

If I remove *res* from pipeline, browser will show correct response (obviously download will not work in that case).

I tried removing Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers before returning .json. I also tried regular .pipe() syntax without any luck.

How to continue using express response object after fail in pipeline? Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time the `catch` block is reached, the socket of the `res` object has already been destroyed by the pipeline. A [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback) "forwards errors" and destroys the destination if an error occurs in the source or along the intermediate transformations.

Try the following:

```js
sqlStream.on("error", function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  if (!res.headersSent)
    res.status(500).json({message: 'Please check the application logs for more details.'}).end();
});
try {
  await pipeline(sqlStream, formatCsvStream, res);
} catch (err) {} // to avoid unhandled promise rejections. No further output here.
```

Comment: Works, error message shows in the browser. But app crashes afterwards because of: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Is there a way to prevent destroy of specific pipe inside pipeline or some kind of before destroy event?

Comment: I don't know if you can influence what a pipeline destroys in case of an error, sorry. But perhaps the error handler gets called twice, I have put in an extra `if` statement.

Comment: Sadly there is none. Here is gist to entire code for you to reproduce if you want to help more - https://gist.github.com/hlozancic/ecdea0f4ea98257dd01f68d6ea4534c1. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does the extra `if (!res.headersSent)` solve the problem?

Comment: Nice! Didn't knew about res.headersSent. It sorted out the problem and with few refactors it will be nice. Hint that res stream was destroyed by the pipeline was very helpful.